# Plot line graph based on selected/filtered rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe of footballers and their premier league fantasy football stats,
I would like to create line plots for each player (x-axis: gameDate, y-axis: points)

Below is a def I created that filters the dataframe based on the player name and attempts the lineplot.

```
def PlotPlayerPoints(df, player):
    df = df.copy()
    df = df.filter(like=player, axis=0)
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))
    plt.title(player)
    sns.lineplot(data=ffmlDf, x="gameDate", y="points", estimator=None)
        
for player in ffmlDf['playerName'].unique():
    PlotPlayerPoints(ffmlDf, player)
```

The lineplot comes through as the exact same for each player,
so my attempt at filtering clearly did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a `hue` parameter. Showing your `df` would help.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.lineplot(x='total_bill', y='size', hue='sex', data=df)
```

`hue` acts like a filter and draws the selected plot for each instance found in the `hue` parameter, so in your case `hue` would need to be the player.

[image]

Unless you want `n` lineplots for each player then, of course, you can use for loop.

Comment: Hello Mate thanks for the speedy reply.
I created a google document to show screenshots of the dataframe and me using hue.

I thought about using hue before but as there are 460 premier league players, it becomes very congested.

google docs link:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IvLPmY0aNMiwSNqnomdsDezRIOtaHXQ2oKJ6CbEwwQw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try to add your data to the original question in a form of code, if not possible a screenshot will do. If you have too many players, you can sort your `df` by a selected metric or group by a club and then plot `n` `lineplots` showing `players` per club or just top n players by y metric. In general, lineplot with `460` lines is not desirable. Try to show what is important, not everything or further summarise the data by grouping of filtering.